# What port does Handoff use?

Tags: network, security, firewall, continuity

It seems that my firewall blocks some Handoff features. When I turn off my firewall it all works as expected.

What port does Handoff use?

Comment: What firewall software and settings do you use? The apple support documents on [ports used](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944) and [network](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060) don't mention 'handoff' or 'continuity' directly. The second document does say "If your firewall supports using hostnames, you might be able to use most Apple services above by allowing outbound connections to *.apple.com", have you tried that?